# Android Testerfield has failed - Android HTTPPost with JSON object

Tags: android, json, http-post, httpclient, logcat

I'm new to using HTTP, more over in Android. I am attempting/have to to authenticate a login sending the required information over HTTP Post using a JSON object.

When I run the app, I login using the login screen which asks for an install to be added into the access url, a username, and a password. I enter those in, hit the confirm button, and then the app crashes and a message comes up saying: "Unfortunately, TesterField has stopped."

I cannot decipher what is being identified in the LOGCAT.

**Will someone please tell me the reason behind this (run-time) error?**

CODE:

```
package name.company.androidlogin;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

    private Button loginButton;
    private TextView resultText;
    private EditText usernameText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private EditText installText;
    private String accessURL = "http://url";
    public final String CONSUMER_KEY = "KEY";
    public final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "SECRET";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);
        usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        installText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_install);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendJson()
    {
        JSONObject jOb;
        try {
            jOb = toJSON();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(accessURL);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jOb.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
            entity.setContentType("application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            resultText.setText(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+" "+response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject();
        try {
            credentials.put("ConsumerSecret", CONSUMER_SECRET);
            credentials.put("ConsumerKey", CONSUMER_KEY);
            credentials.put("Password", passwordText.getText());
            credentials.put("Username", usernameText.getText());
        } finally {
            resultText.setText(credentials.toString(2));
        }
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

LOG CAT:

```
07-16 13:55:50.834: I/ActivityManager(93): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder bnds=[120,402][240,552]} from pid 192
07-16 13:55:50.834: W/WindowManager(93): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
07-16 13:55:50.954: D/dalvikvm(1122): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-16 13:55:50.997: I/ActivityManager(93): Start proc name.company.testerfield for activity name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder: pid=1122 uid=10040 gids={3003}
07-16 13:55:51.134: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{415d4950 Starting name.company.testerfield paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
07-16 13:55:51.474: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2
07-16 13:55:52.474: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{41620b70 name.company.testerfield/name.company.testerfield.URLBuilder paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
07-16 13:55:52.604: D/gralloc_goldfish(1122): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-16 13:55:52.704: I/ActivityManager(93): Displayed name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder: +1s788ms
07-16 13:55:52.974: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0) failed with errno -2
07-16 13:55:55.054: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{415cdbe0 InputMethod paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
07-16 13:55:56.084: D/dalvikvm(147): GC_CONCURRENT freed 306K, 35% free 10784K/16455K, paused 6ms+8ms
07-16 13:56:09.504: D/dalvikvm(93): GC_CONCURRENT freed 483K, 10% free 12354K/13639K, paused 6ms+33ms
07-16 13:56:13.364: D/dalvikvm(376): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 6% free 11433K/12039K, paused 6ms+27ms
07-16 13:56:17.134: D/AndroidRuntime(1122): Shutting down VM
07-16 13:56:17.134: W/dalvikvm(1122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:725)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at name.company.testerfield.URLBuilder.postLoginData(URLBuilder.java:57)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at name.company.testerfield.URLBuilder.onClick(URLBuilder.java:50)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 13:56:17.204: W/ActivityManager(93):   Force finishing activity name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder
07-16 13:56:17.204: W/WindowManager(93): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
07-16 13:56:17.344: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{41642a88  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
07-16 13:56:17.724: W/ActivityManager(93): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4133b488 name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder}
07-16 13:56:17.743: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10005, 1) failed with errno -2
07-16 13:56:17.814: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{41622c28 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
07-16 13:56:18.694: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2
07-16 13:56:28.634: W/ActivityManager(93): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4133b488 name.company.testerfield/.URLBuilder}
```

EDIT:
I should mention some other requirements:
 - set the content type as “application/json; charset=utf-8″
 - will be receiving a cookie as part of the response

THANKS

Comment: This is what you need to notice. 07-16 13:56:17.134: W/dalvikvm(1122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 13:56:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.NullPointerException  Some variable is null, while you try to do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was from attempting to connect to the internet on the main thread. I used AsyncTask to carry out connecting to the internet in the background on a different thread.